# AXIOS POST return result

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, axios, jwt

I have created a non-JWT api call and it works. The moment I added JWT verifyToken it works but I cannot seems to get the return result set from AXIOS POST.

Function 2 --> /userget ----is working I can display result on HTML

Function 7 ---> /api/userget ---It can get data and token but I cannot display on HTML, it goes to "Bad response"

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
function myFunction2() {
    console.log("Going2");
    var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    console.log(userid);
    axios( {
        method: 'post',
        url:'http://localhost:8081/userget',
        data : {
            userid : userid
          }
      })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data.result[0].username );
        var userid = JSON.stringify(response.data.result[0].userid);
        var username = JSON.stringify(response.data.result[0].username);
        var email = JSON.stringify(response.data.result[0].email);

        var userid = JSON.parse(userid);
        var username = JSON.parse(username);
        var email = JSON.parse(email);
        var displaydata = ("User ID : " + userid + "<br><br>Name : " + username + "<br><br>Email :" + email);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = displaydata;
        })
    .catch(function (error) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Bad response";
        });
    }
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
function myFunction7() {
    console.log("Going7");
    var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    console.log(userid);
    console.log("Print local token == " + localStorage.getItem("token"));
    var msgtxt = localStorage.getItem("token");
    axios( {
        method: 'post',
        url:'http://localhost:8081/api/userget',
        headers: {
            'Authorization': `Bearer ${msgtxt}` 
          },
        data : {
            userid : userid
          }
      })
    .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data.result[0].username );
        var userid = JSON.stringify(response.data.result[0].userid);
        var username = JSON.stringify(response.data.result[0].username);
        var email = JSON.stringify(response.data.result[0].email);

        var userid = JSON.parse(userid);
        var username = JSON.parse(username);
        var email = JSON.parse(email);
        var displaydata = ("User ID : " + userid + "<br><br>Name : " + username + "<br><br>Email :" + email);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = displaydata;
        })
    .catch(function (error) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Bad response";
        });
    }
```

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
app.post('/userget', function (req, res) {
const userid = req.body.userid;
console.log ("User id == " + userid)
user.getUser(userid, function (err, result) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(result)
        res.send({result})
      
    } else{
        res.send(err.errno + " No record");
    }
    res.end()
});
```

});

+++++++++++++++++++++

```
app.post('/api/userget', verifyToken, (req, res) => { 
const userid = req.body.userid;
console.log ("User id == " + userid)
jwt.verify(req.token, secretKey, (err, authData) => {
  if(err) {
    res.sendStatus(403);
  } else {
    user.getUser(userid, function (err, result) {
        if (!err) {
            console.log(result)
            res.send({result})
          
        } else{
            res.send(err.errno + " No record");
        }
        res.end()
    });
    res.json({
      message: 'Post created...',
      authData : authData
    });
  }
});
```

});

Error in terminal
/home/ronaldtan/Programming/webservices/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Parser.js:437
throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
at validateHeader (_http_outgoing.js:491:11)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:498:3)
at ServerResponse.header (/home/ronaldtan/Programming/webservices/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:771:10)
at ServerResponse.send (/home/ronaldtan/Programming/webservices/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:170:12)
at ServerResponse.json (/home/ronaldtan/Programming/webservices/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:267:15)
at ServerResponse.send (/home/ronaldtan/Programming/webservices/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
at /home/ronaldtan/Programming/webservices/controller/app.js:170:17
at Query. (/home/ronaldtan/Programming/webservices/model/user.js:44:32)
at Query. (/home/ronaldtan/Programming/webservices/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
at Query._callback (/home/ronaldtan/Programming/webservices/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)

Comment: I have gotten error in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following:

```
user.getUser(userid, function (err, result) {
    if (!err) {
        console.log(result)
        res.send({
            result
        })

    } else {
        res.send(err.errno + " No record");
    }
    res.end()
});
res.json({
    message: 'Post created...',
    authData: authData
});
```

The second statement (`res.json(...)`) is executed before the async-operation `user.getUser(..)` has finished. So once its callback is executed, `res.json` will already have finished and since you are trying to `res.send` again (`res.json` does the same operation under the hood) you get the error.

It seems like you can just remove the `res.json(...)` statement as you want to return the found user, not some info about creating a post.